# Is it possible to have and h2 tag with an h1 class?

Tags: html

Is it possible to have and h2 tag with an h1 class?

```
<h2 class="h1">Test</h2>
```

i need h2 tag for SEO-related thing but I need the style of h1.

I already tried doing this, but no luck

```
h2.h1 {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: You can style your HTML however you like.  What isn't working?

Comment: The CSS is correct and applied properly, just make it look as you want. https://jsfiddle.net/g043g3qf/

Comment: However, it's good practice to don't add classes named as tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style the h2 tag the same way h1 is styled. Inspect the h1 tag and copy its style. Don't try and incorporate h1 as a class for h2, it's a lot easier to just restyle your tag.